CORS errors on Page Builder Content updates
I have encountered a critical problem with Page Builder on Magento 2.4.6-p6. Saving changes often fail on the second attempt due to CORS errors. Specifically, we see:

CORS Error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at xxx from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy.
Page Builder Rendering Lock: [ERROR] Page Builder rendered for 5 seconds without releasing locks.

This results in a persistent "Please wait" loader that prevents us from saving modifications.
How to solve it?

Request the patch ACSD-60169_2.4.6-p6.patch via a support ticket!
If you applied the patches below:

ACSD-49628: Page Builder CORS errors prevent product save.
ACSD-52041: Page Builder rendering doesn’t release locks.

Remove ACSD-49628.patch and ACSD-52041 patch and apply ACSD-60169_2.4.6-p6.patch instead!

If you don't have a directory named m2-hotfixes in the project root, please create one. Patches we provide will be put here.

Copy .patch file(s) to m2-hotfixes directory;

git add m2-hotfixes;

Commit changes;

Push changes;



Hey I'm having the same errors but can't find ACSD-60169 anywhere, can you share a link? Thanks

This still needs to be published by Adobe as a quality patch. When you contact them via support(For cloud atleast), they provide this patch file with a similar response.
